# Selecting NurbsPath as hair particle render object is not showing on the plane in viewport

Tags: 3d-view, particles

Can anyone help me with it as converted into mesh creating multiple points/vertices than less vertices geometry path which will make my old system less laggy

I selected a plane, added a particle system, and selected *Hair*. Under *Render* I changed *Path* to `Object` and under *Object* I selected `NurbsPath` in the *Instance* option as shown in [a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/C_DPPYqw7Zs).

In the video, it appeared instantly on the plane but to me, it was not appearing.

So here is what happened to me in this query:

- First I take a *Nurbspath* from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → *Curve* → *Path*
- Then taken a *BezierCircle*, same as above.
- Then changed the geometry of the *NurbsPath* in *Object Data Properties* to *BezierCurve* and modified the path as grass in *Edit Mode*.
- Then added the plane to use as a ground for grass.
- By selecting the plane added hair particles in *Particle System*.
- Then in the *Hair* tab options went to the *Render* option and changed the instance as *Object* and in the newly appeared *Object* option below the render option I selected the *NurbsPath* (as shown in the image below).

Then instead of the plane having the *NurbsPath* in place of the hair, the plane appeared empty as appeared in the below image.

And I did this all by following a YouTube video in step by step process as shown in it. In that video, it appeared but for me, it didn't.

So, what was the mistake I have done here, and how to rectify it?

[image: screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post the link to the mentioned video?

Comment: Your particle scale is tiny, make them bigger

Comment: Link to the video i mentioned = https://youtu.be/C_DPPYqw7Zs can u check and give me a solution @Blunder

Comment: I have increased the scale number to 3000 from 0.50 as u suggested but still didn't worked @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Comment: Hi. I've followed your instructions and got the same result in Blender 3.2. Now I've watched the video I've noticed the tutor uses Blender 2.92. So I've opened the file in 2.93 LTS and there it is! It's the Blender version. Blender 3.2 got new a new curve type that wil replace the existing curve types (poly, bezier, nurbs) and the hair particle system. Maybe these changes broke something and you can't render particles as curves now in 3.2.

Comment: So it means i have only option of converting geometry into mesh but if u watch the video fully later in the video he used the path as collection so to do that i must have geometry path instead of mesh. Is there any way to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to convert your NurbsPath to a Mesh :

Select NurbsPath press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Apply > Visual Geometry to mesh*

Maybe there's a way to directly render NurbsCurve, but I doubt it.

Comment: Ok, i will try that,  in the video i followed he didn't do anything like this and it appeared for him but i followed step by step of that video still didn't appeared for me, why was it like that

Answer (score 0):

Blender 3.5. I ran into this issue as well. For whatever reason, the nurb path object needs to be converted to a mesh. Right click on the object and convert to mesh. This is the workflow I am using now.