# Export particle hair system as alembic with using nurbs path as instance object

Tags: particles, export, hair, alembic

Good evening. I want to create stylized hair and export it as alembic file and I've got a cool idea: what if I speed up the process using technique from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnU5CmfGXT0&list=LL&index=43), then I'll create particle system where I will use nurbs path (or collection of it) as instance objects and then export it as alembic? There is only one problem for that moment - it doesn't work(.

I've found similar question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272823/selecting-nurbspath-as-hair-particle-render-object-is-not-showing-on-the-plane-i), but I can't just convert hair to mesh - in that case I won't be able to adjust it to head.
Am I missing something? Or, maybe, there is much easier way?